# Realm access from incorrect thread while using realm with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to use realm with kotlin coroutines and make queries inside a new thread using withContext()

What I observe is that **threads are switching in the loop** making realm throws this exception: **Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.**

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            val images = mutableListOf<String>("id1", "id2", ...)
            for (imageId in images) {
                 println("THREAD : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                 val image = realm.where<Image>().equalTo("imageId", imageId).findFirst()
                 delay(1000) // Can lead to an actual switching to another thread
            }
            realm.close()
}
```

As the dispatchers.IO documentation mention here: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html

"This dispatcher shares threads with a [Default][Dispatchers.Default] dispatcher, so using
     * `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }` does not lead to an actual switching to another thread;
     * typically execution continues in the same thread."

I don't understand why thread are switching in the loop.
How to manage realm instance with coroutine properly ?

Comment: `image = realm.where<Image>().equalTo("imageId", imageId).findFirst()` sounds like you are mutating a `var` that you are accessing on a different thread

Comment: I changed to val and still the same, I tried to print the current thread and get : THREAD : DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 THREAD : DefaultDispatcher-worker-5

Comment: So weird, it works sometime and sometime it fails.

Comment: In that case you don't have the code here that actually fails.

Comment: Yes I dont have the complete code here but this is the part that fails, the line where it fails is "val image = realm.where<Image>().equalTo("imageId", imageId).findFirst()". I understand why it fails, it is because it switch from thread inside the loop, but why this behaviour ?

Comment: no the for-loop does not switch threads and you are missing the code that is actually failing

Comment: What is `images` in your code? Isn't it a collection of Realm objects that you created elsewhere and are now accessing from a different thread?

Comment: Images is just a list of String. This exception occured because I had a suspend call inside the loop that cause thread switching to another thread. So should I open a realm instance inside the loop everytime ? isn't it dirty ?

Comment: Maybe I should use Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher() instead of Dispatchers.IO ?

Comment: Evidently you were missing the `delay` call which was quite important :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time a coroutine is suspended, at the time it's resuming the dispatcher will find a thread for it to run on. It's quite likely that it will be a different thread than the one it ran on previously.

Comment: Yes calls I make inside withContext are blocking, they can can make the main thread skip some frame if I run it on the main thread. But the Thread it runs still change.

Comment: It may change _from call to call_, not within a single call. Either that, or you do have a suspending call inside `withContext`.

Comment: You're right, I have a suspending call inside the loop, it explains why, sorry, I edited my code to make my problem clearer

Comment: So we now know why this happens but is there already a best practice on how to use realm in coroutines?

Answer (score 9):

You can run Realm in another new single thread in a Coroutine. For example

```
val dispatcher =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
jobs.launch(dispatcher) {
  // create new Realm instance
}
```